# How using refined to express constraints with constants > 22

Tags: scala, shapeless

I am trying to explore possibilities with refined (and shapeless) to have improved type checking.

I would like to represent, with type, some constraints  of interval or size.

So , with refined, i can writes things like that :

```
type Name = NonEmpty And MaxSize[_32]
type Driver = Greater[_15]

case class Employee(name : String @@ Name, age : Int @@ Driver = refineLit[Driver](18))
```

But, i would like to express contraints with naturals larger.

```
type BigNumber = Greater[_1000]
```

This one doesn't works, because `_1000` is not defined. The last one already defined is `_22`
I can, with shapeless `Succ`, made my own, but it is very cumbersome.

Example :

```
type _25 = Succ[Succ[Succ[_22]]]
type _30 = Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[_25]]]]]
type _40 = Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[_30]]]]]]]]]]
type _50 = Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[_40]]]]]]]]]]
type _60 = Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[_50]]]]]]]]]]
type _70 = Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[_60]]]]]]]]]]
type _80 = Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[_70]]]]]]]]]]
type _90 = Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[_80]]]]]]]]]]
type _100 = Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[_90]]]]]]]]]]
// etc.
```

Is there a better way to express such contraints, or to make `_1000` in a more efficient way ?
Is there something I would have missed ?

**Edit :**

I have tried the Travis proposition :

```
val thousand = shapeless.nat(1000)
```

But this line causes a `StackOverflowError` at compile time (at macro expansion)
If I try with a lesser number, it is ok.

```
val limit = shapeless.nat(50)
type BigNumber = Greater[limit.N]

case class TestBigNumber(limit : Int @@ BigNumber)
```

In my environment, the StackOverflowError is raised for numbers greater than 400.

Moreover, with this code, compilation never ended (using sbt) :

```
val n_25 = shapeless.nat(25)
type _25 = n_25.N

val n_32 = shapeless.nat(32)
type _32 = n_32.N

val n_64 = shapeless.nat(64)
type _64 = n_64.N
```

Comment: You can use `val thousand = nat(1000); type BigNumber = Greater[thousand.N]`, which is a little nicer. I thought it was possible to write something like `Nat.\`100\`.N`, but I may have imagined that.

Comment: @travis : I have a StackOverflowError during macro expansion on the line `val thousand = nat(1000)`, both in eclipse and sbt

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Greater` predicate in [refined](https://github.com/fthomas/refined) supports both Shapeless's type-level natural numbers (`Nat`) and integer singleton types (which are made available by Shapeless's `Witness`). So the following constraints do the same thing:

```
import eu.timepit.refined.implicits._
import eu.timepit.refined.numeric._
import shapeless.{ Nat, Witness }
import shapeless.tag.@@

val a: Int @@ Greater[Nat._10] = 11
val b: Int @@ Greater[Witness.`10`.T] = 11
```

Because of the ways `Nat` and integer singleton types are represented, the latter are much less likely to make the compiler overflow the stack. For example, the following works on my machine:

```
scala> val c: Int @@ Greater[Witness.`10000`.T] = 10001
c: shapeless.tag.@@[Int,eu.timepit.refined.numeric.Greater[Int(10000)]] = 10001
```

Even though `10000` is well past the point where `shapeless.nat(10000)` starts to stack overflow.

---

As a footnote, it is possible to use the `Nat` representation for values larger than 22 without just typing `Succ` a lot:

```
val hundred = shapeless.nat(100)
val c: Int @@ Greater[hundred.N] = 101
```

This is still going to blow the stack for large values, though, so the integer singleton types are the way to go in your case.

Comment: Thanks, it is much better. But, because there is always a but, this code compile well with sbt, but i have an error in eclipse `stable identifier required, but shapeless.Witness.selectDynamic("32") found.`

Comment: @volia17 Sorry, my knowledge of Eclipse is pretty close to non-existent and I don't mind keeping it that way. :) Probably worth a new question?

Comment: As a workaround though you could try `val tenThousand = Witness.\`10000\`` and then `Greater[tenThousand.T]`.

Comment: +1 Great answer. :-) Guess I need to document better that all the numeric predicates work with `Nat` and numeric singleton types. The awesome thing about singleton types is that one can also use a `Double` in those predicates, e.g. `Double @@ Greater[Witness.\`0.5\`.T]`